# How to add example values for parameters in Swagger-UI built by Nancy.Swagger package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, swagger, swagger-ui, nancy

I have used Nancy.Swagger package and MetadataModule to build a Swagger UI for my APIs (according to this link: https://github.com/yahehe/Nancy.Swagger/wiki/Nancy.Swagger-for-Nancy-v2).

I get the UI, but the problem is that I cannot add **example values** for the properties of the object, which is passed as a parameter in body.

I see, for example, this output:

[image]

Here, instead of the word "string", I would like to have a real example value. But I don't know how I can add example values in this approach, and I would appreciate any help.

Snippet from the API and the parameter (object of PRequest):

```
Post("/", async (x, ctx) =>
{   
    PRequest PostRequestModel;
    try
    {
        postRequestModel = this.Bind<PRequest>();
    }
```

Snippet from MetaDataModule:

```
Describe["Post"] = desc => desc.AsSwagger(
            with => with.Operation(
                op => op.OperationId("Post")
                    .Tag("User")
                    .Summary("Post a new User")
                    .Description("This creates a new user.")
                    .BodyParameter(bp => bp.Description("A PRequest object").Name("PRequest").Schema<PRequest>())
```

Comment: can you show your API code?

Comment: @Coding I just added some snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been absolutely ages since you opened this, but I figured I'd share anyways.

First you need a model, like so:

```
public class Model
{
    public string ExampleString { get; set; }
}
```

You need to create an instance of this model filled with whatever examples you want.

```
var exampleModel = new Model() { ExampleString = "foobar" }
```

Then you can add it to the BodyParameter like so:

```
.BodyParameter(para => para.Name("Example").Schema(
    new Schema() { Example = exampleModel }
).Build())
```

I just created a `public static` class to hold all my example objects, then I set them like `Example = Examples.Example1`. I think this is the most readable approach.

A couple problems exist with this approach that I haven't found a solution to (yet). One is that the Example object does not seem to respect whatever settings you're using for Json serialization. Also, I've been unable to get this working concurrently with the Model view, but the Model view was always mostly useless in my eyes anyway. I'll update this if I ever figure any of these issues out. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to test this issue anymore, but thanks a lot for sharing your solution. :)